# Angular 2 understand ViewContainerRef usage with TemplateRef

Tags: javascript, angular

I am implementing the structural directive in **Angular2**. 
In the docs, I saw that I need to inject the `TemplateRef` to get the template element and the `ViewContainerRef`.

```
class TestDirective {
   constructor( private templateRef : TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer : ViewContainerRef ) {
     // this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
   }   
}

<template [ngIf]="condition">
  <p>
    Our heroes are true!
  </p>
</template>
```

In this case what I don't understand which element is the `ViewContainerRef`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inject `ViewContainerRef` the element is the host element of `TestDirective`. If you use `@ViewChild(templateVarNameOrType)` or `@ContentChild(templateVarNameOrType)` it's the element where `templateVarNameOrType` matches.

You should be aware that `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView()` or `this.viewContainer.createComponent()` creates the element or component as sibling of the element `ViewContainerRef` points to, not as many expect as child.

Comment: You can expand your answer to be with examples please, I see many people struggling with this question. thanks.

Comment: The @ViewChild(templateVarNameOrType) or @ContentChild(templateVarNameOrType), and you have duplicate this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView() code

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Was a copy-paste error. Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681 fills the missing gaps.

Comment: And what if I need to create the element as a child?

Comment: You need a `ViewContainerRef` of an element inside the child but I don't know a way to get that, except when the child provides one that it gets itself by `@ViewChild()`.