# What is TemplateRef and ViewContainerRef?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am implementing a directive but I am confused in term of **jquery** and **Pseudo DOM**.
i.e.

How to relate `TemplateRef` and `ViewContainerRef`?

Comment: You might want to read this [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02). Also, your question is very generic, can you make it more specific?

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228712/angular-2-understand-viewcontainerref-usage-with-templateref)

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com: I can see that you have written some outstanding blogs & answers for Angular. Would you please be kind enough to provide inputs on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911385/importance-of-maintaining-states-on-the-ui-side-angular4. I cant find satisfactory answer

Answer (score 1):

TemplateRef : It represents an embedded template that can be used to instantiate embedded

ViewContainerRef: It represents a container where one or more views can be attached.