# Importance of maintaining states on the UI side - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, redux

I worked on `ngRoute` on AngularJS1.X and I have started learning Angular 4 now. One think which I wanted to understand was the significance of maintaining states on the UI.

I know it seems like a silly question but from what I understood about states is all about storing client side data which are important for the proper behavior of the application UI. It is lost once the page is refreshed.

I can do the same by creating a service, isn't it ? What am I missing here.

Can anyone please explain with some proper example?

Comment: your question is a bit vague, I suggest you read this article [Managing State in Angular Applications](https://blog.nrwl.io/managing-state-in-angular-applications-22b75ef5625f) and then come up with a more focused question